# How to center title of a post on my website on CSS?

Tags: css, centering

The title and image of my posts are not aligned with the rest of the website. I unfortunately had to tweak the menu and content a little bit to visually center it on the browser window, but it seems it might have created a 'shift' with the header/image.

example of post with the issue:  http://www.overfit-not.com/the-danger-of-feature-selection-with-random-forests/

I have not been able to do this myself. Below is the code I used to actually center the content of the post relative to the menu.

```
.site-content {
    width: 105%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your entry-header tag is smaller than your entry-content which is `width: 1000px`. You can either do the header bigger or your content smaller. Hope this help you. Try changing `width: 100%` for your content.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.entry-header{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline-block    
}
```

Comment: Playing around with width made it work :) Thanks for your help.